# Range returning a wrong set of Cells

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm using Excel Interop and am trying to return a range of cells relative to a first range of cells that I got from a worksheet. The problem is that the second fetch of the range it's not giving me the expected cells. Here is the code:

```
Range cells = xlWorkSheet.Range[
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 5],
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[9, 9]
];

Range cells2 = cells.Range[cells[2, 2], cells[3, 3]];
```

In the second Range call I was expecting to get the Cells from [6, 6] to [7, 7] (relative to the worksheet, that is). Instead I'm getting [10, 10] to [11, 11].

If I get a cell individually I get the expected one:

```
Range c1 = cells.Cells[2, 2];
```

This returns me the [6, 6] cell. Any thoughts on why I'm getting this behaviour?

Comment: `cells.Range["B2"].Resize[2,2]`

Comment: Just Try
`Range cells2 = cells.Range[cells.Cells[2, 2], cells.Cells[3, 3]];`

Comment: @JohnyL Resize did the job. Thanks for that but do you know why the range approach doesn't work?

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage I had already tried that (using .Cells) but it still gives me the same range I mention in my question.

Comment: I have posted the answer. Please, let me know if it solves your problem. 

Comment: Indexing a range requires *int* values between the [brackets].  It will use cells[2, 2].Value (Value is the default property), surely you did not mean to use the content of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's explanation why you don't get the results you need.

```
enum ColorConstants 
{
    vbYellow = 65535,
    vbRed = 255
}

Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application
{ 
    Visible = true, 
    WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized 
};
Excel.Workbook book = excel.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;

// We have initial range "E5:I9"
Excel.Range cells = sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[5, 5], sheet.Cells[9, 9]];
cells.Interior.Color = ColorConstants.vbYellow; //Color the range

// Now your goal is to get range "F6:G7" (relative to the sheet),
// which is range "B2:C2" (relative to "cells" range)

// Let's dissect why this isn't the result you need

// You try to achieve your goal with this code:
Excel.Range cells2 = cells.Range[cells.Cells[2, 2], cells.Cells[3, 3]];
cells2.Interior.Color = ColorConstants.vbRed;

// However, the result is incorrect:
// it gives you "J10:K11" range:
string addr = cells2.Address[0, 0]; //=> J10:K11

// Let's see why this happens.
// The thing is that the cell, returned by Cells,
// is relative to SHEET - and not to YOUR RANGE.

// Start cell (top-left): its address is "F6"
Excel.Range cell_start = cells.Cells[2, 2];

// End cell (bottom-rigth): its address is "G7"
Excel.Range cell_end = cells.Cells[3, 3];

// So, we have "F6:G7" address.
// Now we must imagine that our initial range "E5:I9" - and namely "E5" - is the start cell of the sheet.
// When you do it, our "F6:G7" relatively to "E5:I9" will be "J10:K11",
// because "F6:G7" goes OUTSIDE the boundaries of "E5:I9".
// If you calculate correctly, it will be our incorrect "J10:K11" range.
// This is why you get incorrect result.

// To calculate the offset correctly,
// you must imagine your range as a small worksheet.
// For instance, for our range "E5:I9":
// • "E5" (statrt cell) can be referred to as:
//    1) cells.Cells[1]
//    2) cells.Cells[1, 1]
//    2) cells.Cells[1, "A"]
//    3) cells.Cells["A1"]
// • "F6" (end cell) can be referred to as:
//    1) cells.Cells[7]
//    2) cells.Cells[2, 2]
//    3) cells.Cells[2, "B"]
//    4) cells.Range["B2"]

// Thus, we need another approach:
cells2 = cells.Range["B2"].Resize[2, 2];
cells2 = cells.Cells[2, 2].Resize[2, 2];
cells2 = cells.Range["B2:C3"];
cells2.Interior.Color = ColorConstants.vbRed; //Color the range
```

Comment: I see now, nice explanation. Just one more question, though: what are we doing when we invoke resize?

Comment: @Leone When you invoke `Resize`, you redefine your range where the starting point is the top-left cell of your original cell. :)

Comment: It's just that the name doesn't seem to fit what I'm trying to do. It seems like we're picking a cell and make several copies of it until we fill the range designated by the parameters that we pass to the Resize indexer. But anyways, it works and it solved my problem so thank you for your help and detailed explanation.

Comment: @LeonelB. I see your concern. Think of `Resize` as a Lego brick wall. When you need to change the size of this wall, you leave only top-left brick of this wall and put the bricks again to the size you need. It's like destroy-and-rebuild. 

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cells.Parent is the xlWorkSheet object in your case.

For completeness, be advised that you can use any of the following and you will get the same successful results you wanted to see:

```
Range cells2 = cells.Parent.Range[cells.Cells[2, 2], cells.Cells[3, 3]];
```

or

```
Range cells2 = xlWorkSheet.Range[cells.Cells[2, 2], cells.Cells[3, 3]];
```

or

```
Range cells2 = cells.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3]];
```

Comment: Did you meant Range cells2 = cells[cells.Cells[2, 2], cells.Cells[3, 3]];? It returns cell [4,4].

Comment: Apologies, try the revised version. Thanks.

Comment: It does work, but how does calling the Parent makes the range behave relativelly to the current range and not the worksheet? Who is the Parent in this call? Is it not the worksheet?

Comment: Please see my expanded answer.